# using LINQ to XML to query inner xml of child nodes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Let's say that I've got this xml:

```
<items>
  <item name="thumb">
    <downloadStream>test1</downloadStream>
    <downloadStream>test2</downloadStream>
    <downloadStream>test3</downloadStream>
  </item>
  <item name="photo">
    <downloadStream>test5</downloadStream>
    <downloadStream>test6</downloadStream>
    <downloadStream>test7</downloadStream>
  </item>
</items>
```

I'm trying to write a LINQ to XML statement that returns me:

{"test5", "test6", "test7"}

In other words, it returns me the inner xml for each "downloadStream" node where the parent node has an attribute of (name="photo").

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
            var rootElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var results = rootElement.
               .Elements()
               .Where( e => e.Attribute("name") == "photo" )
               .SelectMany( e => e.Elements )
               .Select( e => e.Value );
```